# Limit to one simultaneous call for a function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

so, I have in my table, a column that I use as reference.

The reference is build with multiple piece of string, and the last one is a number.

With this sql code in my function, I get the last number

```
SELECT DECODE(MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(numero,INSTR(numero,'/', 1, 4)+1,1000) as Int)), NULL, '0', MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(numero,INSTR(numero,'/', 1, 4)+1,1000) as Int))) +1 into v_nbnumeronum
          from table
          where numero like TO_CHAR(sysdate,'%/YYYY/MM/%');
```

This works fine.

The thing is, as I can call multiple times the stored procedure, where I call the function, the `numero` will be the same for multiple call of the function ( as the table is not yet updated).

Is there a way to have something like :

```
while function hadn't been called

if "function is is used" then wait
else call function

end loop
```

This is aproximative. I don't know if this is possible. I don't have enought knowledge on oracle 10g to know that.

The function works fine, but until a submit is not call, it will always find the same maximum current number, which is not good.

So it works when I know it will be called one time, but when there is more...

**edit :** so, I called this function, to find the maximum number, used in the column `numero`.

This function is called by a stored procedure. And after the function is called, later in the procedure, I insert a row in my table, and `commit` the changes.

The thing is, it can have multiple stored procedure instance at a time. So, until the `commit` is not done, it will always find the same maximum number. So, in the multiple stored procedure that called the function, there will be the same number in the return statement, which is not good.

Thank you.

Comment: The logic is unclear, can you please elaborate what the function is actually supposed to do and how you want to use the function.

Comment: I'd use an Oracle `sequence` and not worry about resetting the numbers at the end of each month. Otherwise you're in for a whole lot of complexity, or a performance-killing serialization (e.g. using DBMS_LOCK to ensure that the function is only called from one session at a time).

Comment: @JeffreyKemp if I reset the number for each month, it is because I have to do it.